# SUSY two colum layout with facing gutters to allow wide spread to work

Tags: sass, susy-compass, susy

I have a layout that I want to achieve but its stumping me. I want to use the 'wide' spread to achieve a visual 'overhang' (Red block in image below).

To get this working, the two columns (Grey in image below) need to have gutters (light grey in image below) that face each other. Cant work out how to do this!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLnQi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this automatically, but Susy is designed to give you access to the math, so you can do what you want with it. There would be various ways to solve this problem. [Here's one option on SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7cf4d8dced64480f34e1).